# Kafka streams - out of sequence side effects from external write

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

```
                                 KafkaProducer send("X", K, V)         (k1, x1)   ┌────────────┐
                              ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────►│ Topic X    │
                              │                                                   │            │
                              │                                       ┌──────────►│            │
                              │                                       │ (k1, x2)  └────────────┘
                              │                                       │
                              │                                       │
                     ┌────────┴─────┐                           ┌─────┴─────────┐
                     │ KStream A    │                           │ KStream B     │
┌───────────┐        │ .from(A)     │      ┌───────────┐        │ .from(B)      │
│Topic A    ├───────►│ .transform() ├──────┤Topic B    ├───────►│ .transform()  ├────►
└───────────┘        │ .peek(x1)    │      └───────────┘        │ .peek(x2)     │
                     │ .to(B)       │                           │ .to(C)        │
                     └──────────────┘                           └───────────────┘
```

I have two Kafka stream applications processing messages A -> B and doing further business processing after that. Each stream application is also writing an event packet to Topic 'X'.

```
stream
    .transform(() -> eventTransformer)
    .peek((key, value) -> {
        eventProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("X", key, value));
    });
```

Stream app A emits event message x1 with key k1, and

Stream app B emits event message x2 with the same key k1 to ensure the same partition

However, I'm noticing that sometimes they are being written out of sequence, x2 before x1, which is causing the event processing to fail for that particular transaction.

How can I guarantee the writes are always in sequence, x1 followed by x2?

I'm happy to explore alternative approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events coming out of order, which you observe, are most likely because of the caching(buffering) in the producer and Kafka Streams.

1. You can configure your producer to minimise latency (mainly `linger.ms` and `batch.size` config parameters). Please, see [Configure Kafka to Minimise Latency](https://www.confluent.io/blog/configure-kafka-to-minimize-latency/) article for more details.
2. Have a look at Kafka Streams caching [Record Caches in DSL](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html#record-caches-in-the-dsl). Setting `CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG=0` might be helpful here.
3. Personally, I do not like the idea of calling `producer.send()` method from your KS application. You can just materialise the stream to a topic with `.to()` method like this

> ```
> var transformed = stream.transform(() -> eventTransformer)
>
> transformed.to("topic-B")
>
> transformed.to("topic-X")
> ```

Comment: Thanks @kikulikov, I'll do a comprehensive test next couple of days with the suggested changes.